# Bulk Edit Email Templates Settings

Tags: email-template

Simple question, we have 50+ email templates that are currently not activated that need to be. I was curious is there a way to do this in bulk or through metadata rather then editing each one individually and spending an hour?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it with an Apex call, from Workbench it looks like the field IsActive on EmailTemplate is writable:

[image]

So this can be done within the metadata with a package. For example, here is an email template meta.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmailTemplate xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>32.0</apiVersion>
    <available>TRUE</available>   <----- EDIT THIS LINE
    <description>Your email template description</description>
    <encodingKey>ISO-8859-1</encodingKey>
    <name>Email Template Name</name>
    <style>none</style>
    <subject>Subject Line of email template</subject>
    <type>visualforce</type>
</EmailTemplate>
```

So once you've edited the files needed simply package and deploy the changes.

> **Bonus Points:**

If you're using an IDE like Sublime Text that lets you search and replace your entire code base you can do this with one click.

[image]